# run query if all satements are succeed

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a query which contains 'INSERT','DELETE' and 'UPDATE' statement. Now my question is "Is it possible no statement run if any other of the statement is failed"

```
$sql=" START Transaction INSERT statement; DELETE statement; UPDATE statement; COMMIT";
```

Comment: Have a look at mysql transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a [MySQL transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html). It will let you to roll back all changes (which was made on transaction) if something goes wrong (e.g. you got an error).

Simple example:

```
<?php 
$all_query_ok=true; // our control variable 
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "dbname");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* disable autocommit */
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);

//we make 4 inserts, the last one generates an error 
//if at least one query returns an error we change our control variable 
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO myCity (id) VALUES (100)") ? null : $all_query_ok=false; 
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO myCity (id) VALUES (200)") ? null : $all_query_ok=false; 
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO myCity (id) VALUES (300)") ? null : $all_query_ok=false; 
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO myCity (id) VALUES (100)") ? null : $all_query_ok=false; //duplicated PRIMARY KEY VALUE 

//now let's test our control variable 
$all_query_ok ? $mysqli->commit() : $mysqli->rollback(); 

$mysqli->close(); 
?>
```